# Quiz about multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading

This is a quiz on multi thread posted at IBM'developerworks site a couple of years ago, which is now unavailable.

The quize is asking:
1. What's the problem with this code
2. How can you improve this code

I wonder what the exact answer to this quiz is.

```
class HelloRun implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println( ">>>" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": started");
        if( Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("one") ){
            stepA();    
        } else {
            stepB();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void stepB() {
            System.out.println("started B");
            System.out.println("Do something");
            System.out.println("end B");
    }

    private synchronized void stepA() {
            System.out.println("started A");
            System.out.println("Do something");
            System.out.println("end A");        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloRun helloRun = new HelloRun();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(helloRun, "one");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(helloRun, "two");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: what answer? it will print stepA() and stepB() print statements. there is no need of synchronized so performance will be good.

Comment: Did you run it? @virendrao: Performance of System.out.println?

Comment: @Thomas i am telling why we need "synchronized" in method?

Comment: synchronized: to avoid the line triples getting mixed up on standard output.

Comment: @laune did you ran program? try with and without synchronized keyword

Comment: This is a really bad quiz question, and I wouldn't waste time with try to solve it.  The problem is that since the quiz doesn't say what the code is supposed to  do, we can't actually say what is wrong with it.

Comment: @virendrao The fact that there is no mixup without synchronized doesn't mean that there is no potential race condition on the PrintStream.

Answer (score 3):

I guess, the problem is that the same `Runnable` is used for both threads and it synchronizes on itself. Thus threads cannot actually perform `stepA` and `stepB` in parallel. To fix this you can either create two `HelloRun` instances:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new HelloRun(), "one");
Thread t2 = new Thread(new HelloRun(), "two");
```

Or remove the `synchronized` keywords.

Comment: Agree with you thats what i am saying no need for synchronized

Comment: @virendrao, if it's assumed to be a part of some bigger task, then probably synchronization would be necessary. Current code is useless anyways as `System.out.println` is also synchronized, thus starting threads just to print something to stdout is insane idea.

Comment: @virendrao - We can't say that unless we know what the code is supposed to do.  And we simply DON'T KNOW.

Comment: yeah but here its print only thats why i said it... but with only one runnable how two threads dont wait for each other when its synchronized on one of runnable object in this case

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is that you can interleave messages out of synchronized block:

```
>>> one: started
>>> two: started
started B
Do something B
end B
started A
Do something A
end A
```

or

```
>>> one: started
>>> two: started
started A
Do something A
end A
started B
Do something B
end B
```

or

```
>>> one: started
started B
Do something B
end B
>>> two: started
started B
Do something B
end B
```

To solve this interleaves you can add synchronized to the run method instead of the stepA and stepB.

Instead if you can interleave operations without problems you can remove synchronized from stepA and stepB.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's a design issue. If you want two threads doing different things, it should not be implemented in one class. There's a clean code principle called [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Also, the code contains [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29). Once you change the name of a thread, it does something completely different, which is totally unexpected.

And as mentioned by [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c), you can't really tell what the code is supposed to do, so it's hard to say whether it is correct or not and what bug needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what was the expected output 
However, technically you can optimize in this way

Option-1

```java
class HelloRun implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println( ">>>" + name + ": started");
        System.out.println("started " + name);
        System.out.println("Do something");
        System.out.println("end " + name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloRun helloRun = new HelloRun();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(helloRun, "one");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(helloRun, "two");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Option-2

```
class HelloRun implements Runnable {

    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    @Override
    public void run() {
       
       try { 

          lock.lock();

          String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
          System.out.println( ">>>" + name + ": started");
          System.out.println("started " + name);
          System.out.println("Do something");
          System.out.println("end " + name);

       } finally {

          lock.unlock();

       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloRun helloRun = new HelloRun();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(helloRun, "one");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(helloRun, "two");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```